# I want to scale mariadb database for huge number of query requests

Tags: mariadb, moodle, galera

I use Moodle on centos7 with Php, Mariadb, Nginx. There are huge number of users that use this Moodle. If the number of users grows more than 300user per sec, the Moodle has delay in response and seems to be hanged!

I read about:

- Galera (multi master clustering with 3nodes)
- slave-master (separate read and write)
- MaxScale
- increase ram and cpu (I have up to: 288GB ram, 24coreCPU, SSD drive)

What is the best practice to serve huge number of requests without delay? How can I scale my database (because it is the bottleneck)? I want scale it for serve huge request (most of them is `read` from database)

Comment: What is a "user per second"??  Perhaps you mean "query per second"?

Comment: What query/queries are you running?  Maybe they need a better index?

Comment: Are you talking about just reads?  Or also writes?

Comment: Please don't ask about "throwing hardware at the problem" until we have discussed the item above.

Comment: 50 user per second = about 5*50 query per second

Comment: also what about: 500 user per second = about 5*500 query per second?

Comment: If that means 500 connections per second, that is extremely high.

Comment: Yes, and my question is: How can I scale mariadb database for huge number of query requests? If you can explain the best practice or tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB (and MySQL) can scale 'infinitely' for reads by using Replication and sending read requests to Slave servers.

500 *connections per second* is very high.  (But I don't know what the practical limit is.)

There are several extra tools that can do "connection pooling".  Search for this; it may let you go well past 500 *logical* connections on a single server.

In the case of Galera, you could have 3 read-write nodes, plus any number of Slaves hanging off each of the 3.

For simple Master-Slave, there can be any number of Slaves hanging off the one Master.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you can do generic MySQL/MariaDB tuning first, and use a recent version of Moodle (3.7 is current right now)

After that, one thing you can check is how you have sessions implemented.

https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Session_handling

This page also has many more tips:

https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Performance_recommendations

Comment: Yes, I do all the above, also I use Redis for session and cache. My problem is the `database`.